# build multiple shared libraries

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Hi I have a java program which has to invoke a native program, and this native program are given by two so files.  So I create my so file in order to use this native program APIs to do something for my java program.  I was trying to merge two so files with my created so file into single one, and run my java program. However, it seems that it failed this way. To be more concrete, here is my example.

I have a java program A which has to invoke some native code. Therefore I've written some native code and built it as a shared library (called: C.so).

Unfortunately, the native code I've written have to use other code which is in other so files. (A.so, B.so)

Thus, any ideas how to compile my so file with A.so and B.so in order to make my java program work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following:

- When you link c.so, you are listing a.so and b.so on the command line.
- When you run ldd on c.so, you see a.so and b.so.
- When you run, you set -Djava.library.path to include the directory containing all three.
- When you run, you do NOT set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory containing all three.

You will get the desired results if you set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the directory with the libraries in it.

For more explanation, and an alternative, see https://github.com/bimargulies/jni-origin-testbed.

Comment: Yes, Idd gives me a.so and b.so and I did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include all 3 libraries. I still get unsatisfiedlinkerror, I couldn't figure it out why...

Comment: Your next port of call is the LD_DEBUG environment variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the full text of your exception error message. You did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the *directory* containing the files, not to individual file pathnames, right?